# ASP.Net Web API Route based on HTTP Method

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Is there any way to route based on the HTTP method specified in the request? I'm looking to have a GET and PUT at the same URI, but I can't seem to find the option to set the route between the two. The [HttpGet] and [HttpPut] attributes merely act as filters, so a PUT request is hitting the first action and erroring out with a 405 since it hits the GEt handler first.

What I want to do
~/User/PP GET -> UserController.GetPrivacyPolicy
~/User/PP PUT -> UserController.UpdateUserPrivacyPolicy

Whats currently happening
~/User/PP GET -> UserController.GetPrivacyPolicy
~/User/PP PUT -> UserController.GetPrivacyPolicy
(this errors out because i have a [HttpGet] filter on the GetPrivacyPolicy method)

Update:
Just to compliment what was posted below, it looks like I misunderstood how the [HttpGet] and [HttpPut] attributes work, they ARE part of the routing process. I was able to achieve my desired result with the following

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/User/PP")]
    public string GetPrivacyPolicy()
    {
        return "Get PP";
    }
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("~/User/PP")]
    public void UpdatePrivacyPolicy()
    {
        return "Put PP";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do is create your controller with identically named actions but decorated with different Http method attributes

```
public class UserController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PrivacyPolicy(int id) {
        // Put your code for GetPrivacyPolicy here
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult PrivacyPolicy(int id, YourViewModel model) {
        // Put your code for UpdatePrivacyPolicy here
    }

}
```

Of course there are appropriate actions for the other methods e.g. `HttpPost`, `HttpDelete`, `HttpPatch`.

Comment: The attributes are only acting as filters, what you have done is overloaded the PrivacyPolicy method. I can do this, but I'm not actually passing in any paremeters to the action.

Comment: Ok wait, maybe I was wrong... The attributes DO act as part of the routing.

Comment: Yeah, they work a little differently to your normal overloaded method. Try `POST`ing with just an id and you'll get a nice little 404.